# Prove by induction that $ \ \forall n \ge 2, \ 2^{n+1} > n^{2} + 3$

Tags: inequality, proof-writing, induction

Question:

> Prove by induction that $$ \ \forall n \ge 2, \  2^{n+1} > n^{2} + 3$$

My attempt:

Base case is trivial.

Suppose that $ n \ge 2$ and   $\  2^{n+1} > n^{2} + 3$

WTS $ \  2^{n+2} > (n+1)^{2} + 3$

$ 2^{n+2} = 2.2^{n+1}> 2(n^2 + 3) = 2n^2 + 6 = n^2 + n^2 + 2n -2n +6 = (n^2+2n+1) + 3 + (n^2 -2n+2) = (n+1)^2 + 3 + (n^2 -2n+2)$.

I am not sure what to do from here. How can I show $ (n^2 -2n+2) > 0?$

Comment: An alternative approach is to note that $$2n^2+6=n^2+n^2+6\geq n^2+2n+6=(n+1)^2+5>(n+1)^2+3.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$n^2-2n+2=(n^2-2n+1)+1=\dots$$

Comment: Isn't $ \  (n^2-2n+1)+1 = (n-1)^{2} + 1 > 1$?

Comment: @JoshMitkitzel Yep, you got it

Comment: But I need $ > 0$

Comment: Oh wait if its $ >1 \implies >0$

Comment: Is that correct?

Comment: @JoshMitkitzel yes, that is correct

Answer (score 0):

$n^2-2n+2=(n-1)^2+1>0$.

By the way, this reasoning gives also the proof without an induction:
$$2^{n+1}-n^2-3=(1+1)^{n+1}-n^2-3\geq$$
$$\geq1+(n+1)+\frac{(n+1)n}{2}+\frac{(n+1)n(n-1)}{6}-n^2-3=$$
$$=\frac{(n-1)(n^2-2n+6)}{6}>0.$$